# Differences between "weit" and "weit entfernt"

Tags: difference, usage, phrase

What is the difference between *weit* and *weit entfernt*? Which (if any) is the correct version?

> Er wohnt weit von mir.
>   Er wohnt weit entfernt von mir.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there is a difference.

*Weit* is not commonly used for distances (i.e. in the sense of "far") without being accompanied by "entfernt" or "weg". *weit* standing alone can be used for clothing, meaning a wide fit, or for a *wide landscape* (i.e. in the sense of "wide", a close relative).

> Er wohnt weit weg von uns
>
> Er wohnt weit entfernt von uns.

Both meaning "He lives far away from us"

but:

> Ich habe abgenommen. Jetzt sind mir alle meine Hosen zu weit.

(I lost weight. Now all my pants are too wide)

or

> Nach dem Wasserfall öffnet sich die Schlucht weit zu einem See.

Beyond the waterfall the ravine widens towards a lake.

Comment: Danke sehr. By the way, Google translates your last sentence "Now all my pants are too far":)

Comment: Google knows where my pants are? Need to check my privacy settings.

Comment: Google knows, where your pants are absent :)

Comment: You can use “weit” without “weg” in the sense of “a long way”: “It’s a long way to Tipperary” → »Es ist weit bis Tipperary«, “Are we there yet?” → »Ist es noch weit?« (Is it still a long way to go?)

Comment: @tofro, can't stop laughing

Answer (score 3):

The following two sentences are correct. They both express a geographical distance.

> Er wohnt weit entfernt von mir.
>   Er wohnt weit weg von mir.

In your first sentence, *Er wohnt weit von mir*,  I am missing something. It's not wrong, but I would like more context. It could be a geographical distance, but it could be also a poetic expression of an emotional distance between two persons.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no difference.

I think most commonly you would use:

> Er wohnt weit weg von mir.